# Handling Back To Back HTTP Posts SWIFT 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, api, post, swift4

I currently trying to fetch some data from the server. In order to do so, I have to create a JSON(req1) object and send it as a request to first API. Then, the API returns to me a JSON(res1). From that JSON(res1), I have to extract some data (very lengthy, let's call it Data1) and create another JSON object(req2) and hit another API with it as a request and wait for a response(res2).

Now, it's a back to back function. When I call the first API, it takes a long time to respond and by that time, my second API gets called. Thus, I get an error from the server. How should I over come this?

ALGO:

1. Call API_A()
2. Received JSON_A
3. Extract JSON_A
   4.Call API_B(JASON_A.someparts)
4. Received JSON_B
5. Extract JSON_B

Below here is the code:

```js
let json1 = JSON()
let json2 = JSON() //my final result

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     firstApiHit { () -> () in
            secondApiHit(jsonV: json1)
        }
    }

func firstApiHit(handleComplete:(()->())){
 let url1 = URL(string : firstApiURL) 
 let json: [String: String] = ["Data1:Data1Rest"]
 let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
 json1 = httpPost(jsonData: jsonData!, url: url1!)  //hit to the first API!
 handleComplete()
}

func secondApiHit(jsonV : JSON){
 let url1 = URL(string : secondApiURL)
 var value = String()
 extractedValue = String(describing:jsonV["DataX"])
 var json = [String: String]()
 json = ["Data1":extractedValue]
 let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    let json2 = httpPost(jsonData: jsonData!, url: url2!) // my final result!
  //Need the json2 as the final Result!!
}
    
func httpPost(jsonData: Data, url: URL) -> JSON {
 if !jsonData.isEmpty {
  var request = URLRequest(url: url)
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
  request.httpBody = jsonData
  request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { (openTasks: [URLSessionTask]) in
            print("open tasks: \(openTasks)")
           }
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {   
               // check for fundamental networking error
                 print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                 return
                }
       if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           
     // check for http errors
    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
   }
                  
   let jsonX = JSON(data: data) //extracting the data! 
  } 
     task.resume()
 }
    return jsonM
}
```

Comment: "Thus, I get an error from the server" -- Why "thus"? What's the reason? What kind of error?

Comment: You may want to check out Alamofire.

Comment: The error is that, I cannot extract the whole of the JSON from the first response and thus, my second request is incomplete, resulting in the second response being failure! Failure as in I get a 400 code, instead of 200 and so my JSON comes back as null.

Comment: "httpPost()" calls `URLSession.shared.dataTask()` which is async. so `jsonM` has 99,99% percent of being nil when "returns" is called. Use closure.

Comment: @Larme could you may be give me a code or something? I have problems using closures! Please?

Comment: I just noticed: don't use globals! Always a sign of bad code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`httpPost(...)` returns before `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...)` is finished, because the latter is run asynchronously.

In `firstApiHit(...)`, you should not call `handleComplete()`, but pass it on to `httpPost(...)`. You also need to pass the JSON around as parameter.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstApiHit { json in
        secondApiHit(jsonV: json)
    }
}

func firstApiHit(handleComplete: JSON -> Void){
    ...
    json1 = httpPost(jsonData: jsonData!, url: url1!, handleComplete)
}

func httpPost(jsonData: Data, url: URL, responseHandler: (JSON) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        ...                                   
        let jsonX = JSON(data: data)
        responseHandler(jsonX)
    }   
}
```

You *definitely* need to learn how to use closures and, more specifically, the response handler pattern. Otherwise you'll be in a world of pain again and again.